# Get type from a class-constructor in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to extract a type from a class-constructor?

Instead of:

```js
function passValues<T>( values:T ){}
```

Is it possible to pass the class as in the example below and let typescript figure out the type of T, from the first parameter?

```js
class MyClass {
    p:number
}

passValues(MyClass, { p:1 })

function passValues<T>( ctor:???, values:T) {}
```

Comment: What is the point of this? What are trying to do?

Comment: @kmp, I am investigating the possibility of passing a pointer to the prototype to, for example, make use of "statics" attached to it by decorators.

Comment: If you want to get acces to your properties and functions inside `MyClass` you can pass an instance as a parameter, eg. `passValues(new MyClass(), { p:1 })` or `const myClass = new MyClass(); passValues(myClass, { p:1 })`

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by making the class type generic and using the utility type `ConstructorParameters<T>`:

```js
function passValues<T extends { new(...params: any[]): any }>(
  classObj: T, 
  values: ConstructorParameters<T>
): void {

}
```